# std::future gives me error 3, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I use external C library to load TTF font from file. I implemented simple class that caches fonts in a map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::future<stbtt_fontinfo> > fontCache;
```

The `stbtt_fontinfo` contains the internal info about loaded font. I have three other methods. Method that actually loads the font and is launched inside `std::future`'s thread:

```
stbtt_fontinfo ShapeText::FontCache::loadFont(const std::string& fontPath)
{
    // used to save parsed font
    stbtt_fontinfo font;

    std::ifstream input( fontPath, std::ios::binary );
    if(input.is_open()) {
         // do something to load the font
    }

    return font;
}
```

And a method to put new entry in cache:

```
void ShapeText::FontCache::getFontLater(const std::string& fontPath)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::future<stbtt_fontinfo>>::iterator pos = fontCache.find(fontPath);
    if(pos==fontCache.end()) {
        fontCache.insert(std::make_pair(fontPath, std::async(&ShapeText::FontCache::loadFont, this, fontPath)));
    }
}
```

The `std::async(&ShapeText::FontCache::loadFont, this, fontPath)` should start the loading function in new thread and return a `std::future` for it. I did verify that the code gets launched indeed.

Last method serves for loading the fonts, which blocks if the font is not loaded yet:

```
stbtt_fontinfo ShapeText::FontCache::getFont(const std::string& fontPath)
{
    // If the font is not in cache yet, start loading it
    getFontLater(fontPath);
    try {
        // wait until the font is loaded
        return fontCache[fontPath].get();
    }
    catch (const std::future_error& e) {
        const char* msg = e.what();
        const std::error_code code = e.code();
        std::cout<<"ERROR: cannot read value from future font: "<<msg<<"\n";
        // return invalid font
        stbtt_fontinfo font;
        font.cff.data = nullptr;
        font.numGlyphs = 0;
        return font;
    }
}
```

But I get an error in the `try catch` block:

```
ERROR: cannot read value from future font: îţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţłjpYŹ
```

You can see that the `what()` return value is broken. The `error_code` value is 3. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it would be nice if you could change your question to have a much smaller reproducer

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using GCC. I already found the error, it's in the code above clearly visible and was caused because I use futures incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that future cannot be copied into the map like that. Instead, `std::shared_future` must be used. Therefore, the array/map of futures must look like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_future<YourType> > futureCache;
```

And appending to the array must look like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_future<YourType> >::iterator pos = cache.find(fontPath);
if(pos==cache.end()) {
      std::shared_future<YourType> shared = std::async(&YourClass:callback, this, argument1).share();
      cache.insert(std::make_pair(stringKey, shared));
}
```

The key here is `std::future`'s method `share()` which invalidates the original future and instead provides shared future, which can be copied without any limits.